# Resizing a textual material

Tags: graphics, resize

In this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} %for \resizebox
\begin{document}

ABC

\resizebox{0.3\textwidth}{!}{ABC}

\end{document}
```

I use `\resizebox` to scale textual material. The output looks rather pleasing:

[image]

However, I have heard critique of using the `\resizebox` command (it leads to inconsistent fonts) and even regrets of ever having released this command.

How would a versed Latex expert tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For text, use a scalable font and just resize the font.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx} %for \resizebox
\begin{document}

ABC

\resizebox{0.3\textwidth}{!}{ABC} (NOT THIS)

{\fontsize{48}{52}\selectfont ABC} (BUT THIS)

\end{document}
```

[image]

The size was selected, not calculated.  If one needed the result **precisely** as `.3\textwidth`, I would suggest using `\resizebox`, but on something that is close to the final result.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx} %for \resizebox
\begin{document}
ABC

\resizebox{0.3\textwidth}{!}{ABC} (NOT THIS)

{\fontsize{48}{52}\selectfont ABC} (BUT THIS)

\resizebox{0.3\textwidth}{!}{\fontsize{48}{52}\selectfont ABC} (PRECISELY, THIS)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you calculate 48 and 52?

Comment: @Viesturs I didn't calculate them.  I selected them to desired size.

Comment: @Viesturs See my edit, for the case where a precise width is a requirement.